# Bash shell script calling an external program isn't displaying output to the current terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, raspberrypi

I'm new to shell scripts. I'm making a headless raspberry pi that hacks WiFi networks (for educational purposes) with a program called [wifite](https://github.com/derv82/wifite2). The plan is for it to then send an email to with an attachment of the output (not implemented yet).

So this program is interactive so I have to send keyboard input I do that via [xdotool](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool). The main issue is that when I try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> after some time it sends the input to the current terminal on screen but wifite runs on the background and I get no output to the terminal.

Now that's fine I do not need onscreen output but I need to be able to send keyboard input to wifite somehow and i think the easiest way to is to force wifite to output to the current terminal so xdotool can send keyboard inputs. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1m
`sudo wifite --kill | tee output.txt`
sleep 1m
`xdotool key ctrl+c`
`xdotool key Enter`
```

Let me know if there is anything I can do to make the script better. Perhaps i could use a more effective programs within the script. All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using backticks in the `sudo` command? Why are you single-quoting the last two commands?

Comment: I read somewhere that backtics must be used when running external applications and the quotes are a formatting mistake sorry.

Comment: @HarissGills you can use the [edit] button under your post to correct the formatting

Comment: @steeldriver thanks got that fixed now

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48392/understanding-backtick/48393